# Google Timeline overlapping timesheets

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have created a timeline and sometimes there are two timesheets in a row. It is not a problem, but I would like to show them in one line with overlap.

Please see this example:

[image]

So the less line should be shown as a part of the bigger line.

Google's Visualization API is amazing, a very good thing, but it is not so well documented yet.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be an option for that. Best way I can think of is checking for overlaps manually, and changing the end date of the overlapped bar to the start of the other (in this case, change de end date of your small bar with the start of the big one). Could make an example if you want

Comment: Yes, I am interested in this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you already had your data sorted, you could do something like this:

```
var data=[
    ['George Washington', new Date(1779, 3, 29), new Date(1790, 2, 3)],
    ['George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    ['John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)],

];

for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){ // for each row
    if(data[i-1][0]==data[i][0]){ //if the previous one has the same label   
        if(data[i-1][2] > data[i] [1]){ // if the previous end date is greater than the start date of current row
                data[i-1][2]=data[i] [1] // set the previous end date to the start date of current row
        }
    }
}
```

You can view an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9GbNP/33/

Comment: I am using SQL querys to get the necessary data, I have sorted it by names and groupped(because of full duplicates) in JS, but this code do not working.

Comment: Well, could you make an example in jsfiddle with your data?

Comment: Well, check the resulting data from the sql query on the front end

Comment: Yes, I have checked, it is in JSON format, the API uses it, but this code snippet doesn't do anything with my data.

Comment: It says: ReferenceError: drawVisualization is not defined

Comment: I think, this is the correct solution, logically it seems great, but please it is not working!

Comment: Sorry but cant help much without the code that is causing the error

Comment: I only have a formatted data like this(my code is working perfectly): [{"c":[{"v":"Sample Name"},{"v":"Sample Desc"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,0,0,0)"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,1,0,0)"},{"v":"#3030D1"}]},

Comment: @KovacsAkos you are missing the cols there, thats only the rows. Check https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example for correcto format

Comment: @KovacsAkos Here is an example with that data format: http://jsfiddle.net/6garoxvu/2/ uncomment the code for it to work

Comment: @juvian Hi,Juvian.I implement your code on my Timeline Chart but I got an error "Invalid data row#.. start>end" is this mean we can't hack the chart with this code anymore? Anyway,the data in your Example code seems to have only one year but my data has several ranges of year.

Comment: @WonderP keep in mind that I assumed that the data was already sorted by start date. Should keep working fine if its sorted right. If you have any trouble make a fiddle and I can check