# Google Timeline chart to display 2 rows of same names

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to display 2 rows with duplicated row name, am following this thread of discussion:

[Google Timeline overlapping timesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680289/google-timeline-overlapping-timesheets)

but I want 'George Washington' to be display in 2 rows, not in same row.

```
var data=[
  ['George Washington', new Date(1779, 3, 29), new Date(1790, 2, 3)],
  ['George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
  ['John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
  ['Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
];
```

The solution showing in: http://jsfiddle.net/9GbNP/33/ is not exactly what I wanted, because it treat 'George Washington' as 1 entry. In my case, it is 2 entries.

After seeing 'WhiteHat' answer, which worked for above case, I realized my case is more complicated. More descriptions:

```
var data=[
  [1, 'George Washington', new Date(1779, 3, 29), new Date(1790, 2, 3)],
  [2, 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
  [3, 'John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
  [3, 'John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
  [4, 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
];
```

Each row is had hidden field, which is 1st column. What I expect:

1) 'George Washington' to be displayed in 2 rows, as each is unique.

2) 'John Adams' to be displayed in 1 row (it has 2 bars), as it's 1 item in my case.

If using:

```
timeline: {
  groupByRowLabel: false
}
```

the option is conflicting with 2 case.

It should be grouped by hidden field column 0, not by column 1.

Does 'groupByRowLabel' support hidden column? I guess that's the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options)...

```
timeline: {
  groupByRowLabel: false
}
```

> If set to `false`, creates one row for every dataTable entry. The default is to collect bars with the same row label into one row.

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {

  var data = [
    ['George Washington', new Date(1779, 3, 29), new Date(1790, 2, 3)],
    ['George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    ['John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'Name'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows(data);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: false
    }
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

there aren't any standard config options to handle both situations

you would need to manually change the label,
on the chart (`'ready'` event)
and the tooltip (`'onmouseover'` event)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var data=[
    ['0|George Washington', new Date(1779, 3, 29), new Date(1790, 2, 3)],
    ['1|George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    ['John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    ['John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'Name'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows(data);

  var options = {
    height: 400
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (label) {
      if (label.textContent.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        label.textContent = label.textContent.split('|')[1];
      }
    });
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (props) {
    var tooltipLabel = container.getElementsByTagName('span');
    if (tooltipLabel.length > 0) {
      if (tooltipLabel[0].innerHTML.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        tooltipLabel[0].innerHTML = tooltipLabel[0].innerHTML.split('|')[1];
      }
    }
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: Hi HiteHad, it worked but I realized my case is more complicated. I added more description in original post.

Comment: If keep same config, there will be 5 rows. Solved my 1st problem. For "John Adams", if changing to unique name before 'ready' event fires, it's already displayed as 2 rows, which is configured by the 'groupByRowLabel: false', which means regardless unique or not, it's displayed as 2 rows for " John Adams".

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Check the John Adams row. Its again show 2 displays.. :(

Comment: @karthikSWOT check the difference b/t John Adams and George Washington in the __EDIT__, John is on one row, George has two rows

Comment: *Run the Code snippet*. John Adams shows duplicate timeline.

Comment: @karthikSWOT you can see George is listed twice, John once. Two bars, One row. Which is what the OP needed. If you need something else, please ask a question and I will try to help. no need to downvote...